# Valid Reasons to Close Questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Currently, we have the following official reasons to close a question:

- Duplicate
- Off topic due to:

  - General Programming Question
  - No objective winning criterion
  - Belongs on another site
- Unclear what you're asking.
- Too broad
- Primarily opinion based

However, there are other valid reasons to close a question, which are not in the close interface, due to space limitations or otherwise. I think it would be a good idea to make a list of such reasons here. These are things to look out for when considering closing a question, even though they're not common enough to warrant a custom entry.

Here are some such reasons:

- [Too narrow - only one reasonable solution in a given language.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/too-trivial-close-vote)
- [Not primarily about programming, e.g. primarily artistic.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/the-line-between-art-and-programming)

Are there other important categories that we should keep in mind, even though they don't come up enough to have their own close vote entries?

Comment: "Not primarily about programming" can use a custom "Off topic" reason. There's no need to add such custom reasons to the interface unless the same one is being used quite frequently.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. This question is a listing of commonly used custom "Off topic" reasons.

Comment: To find others, you could use a query similar to [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/edit/339421), with variations on the keywords, etc. From my initial few searches, it doesn't seem to happen very often.

Comment: @Geobits while its still not linked, there is a 'question close stats' page accessible under tools for users with delete privileges: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks, I completely forgot about that page.

Answer (score 10):

As discussed on chat, when we started using custom "Off topic" reasons we lost the default one. But it would actually be useful. So I propose adding a custom off topic reason:

> This question is off topic for this site, as defined in the [Help Center](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It's hard for me to deliberately misspell *centre* like that, but I managed it.

Comment: I guess I *have* to +1 this since I brought it up in chat, huh? Even if your spelling judgement is misguided...