# Adding a "Too Narrow" close option

Tags: discussion, policy, close-reasons

For multiple recent questions, people have wanted to close a question because the question was too narrow - not enough variety of potential answers to make it interesting.

Those questions were: [Sign that word!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54945/sign-that-word), , and [Fibonacci in +!()[]script](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55218/fibonacci-in-script).

The desire for such a close reason has come up before, leading to [Too trivial Close Vote](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/too-trivial-close-vote), where the clear most upvoted option was adding the following:

> **Too Narrow**
>
> There are either too few possible ways to answer, or answers would
>   only differ in the language used.

1. Would it be possible to add this close reason, or is there something preventing us?
2. If we can't add that close reason, what should we do if we encounter such a question, and would like to vote to close it?

Comment: "Too Narrow" would probably depend a lot on the language you're using. "Sign that word!" is clearly too narrow for GolfScript, but when it comes to Brainfuck...

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, if there is enough support from the community, moderators can add a custom close option under the off-topic sub-menu (we already have two: belongs on Stack Overflow, and is missing an objective winning criterion).
2. You can always use a custom off-topic close vote:

   [image: screenshot]

To address the question of whether such a close reason is necessary, I don't think there's currently a pressing need (although I certainly wouldn't oppose creating one, if it was demonstrated that there would be a significant benefit in adding this close reason). [The](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19846/3808) community [already](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38295/3808) seems [to do](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28567/3808) a pretty [good](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36850/3808) job of [handling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5994/3808) these on [its own](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28715/3808) (all of these links require 2k+ reputation to view, as they have been deleted by various PPCG users; suffice to say, none of them are very interesting challenges).