# Can we vote to close challenges as impossible?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[Related reasons but not the same](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/too-trivial-close-vote), [2](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5782/adding-a-too-narrow-close-option)

[This challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51039/recursive-zipper-reincarnation) is currently in the process of being closed as 'too-narrow', which in this context means "this challenge is too hard/has too many restrictions, and thus is off-topic".

I don't think we should allow this.  Compare to [Build a working game of Tetris in Conway's Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/build-a-working-game-of-tetris-in-conways-game-of-life). Both are ridiculously hard, but neither have been proven impossible yet.

Do we vote to close challenges because they are too hard?

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9022/unspoken-challenge-rules)

Comment: I think you're strawman-ing a bit. The exact text of the close is `I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too narrow. This question is less likely to be solved than the one for creating Tetris in CGOL.` which is a far cry from `voting to close challenges as impossible.`

Comment: @AdmBorkBork it seems to be being closed as too-hard to me, what else would that message mean?

Comment: My point is you're asking two questions in your question. *Too hard* does not equate to *impossible*, and neither of those address the close reason as being *too narrow*.

Answer (score 5):

## We should only close challenges that are provably impossible

"Solve the halting problem" should be closed as off-topic because it's provably impossible. The challenge in question here should not be closed for that reason, because it's theoretically possible.

Comment: Or even if it's not possible, it still hasn't been proven as such.

Comment: @Riker That's a subjective problem - one could say it hasn't been proven possible, but one could also say that it hasn't been proven impossible. It's a glass-half-empty versus glass-half-full problem. My stance is, if it's not provably impossible, it's fair game for a challenge.